# avoid duplicate entries, not key field

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table, which has two columns

```
key -> Primary Key, auto incremented
reqNumber -> This is a custom generated value
```

the reqNumber is structured as year/month/day/number, where number is the number of times a request was made that day.  so for example, if 3 requests were made today and 2 yesterday, the table would have

```
key    reqNumber
1      2013/07/16/001
2      2013/07/16/002
3      2013/07/17/001
4      2013/07/17/002
5      2013/07/17/003
```

the problem i'm having is sometime multiple users save at the same time.  the proc that does the save, first checks how many were created today and then adds 1 to that, so for the above it would see 3 were created today so the next one would be 4.  After that it does the insert.

but if two users hit save at the same time, they both get 4, which means when the insert happens i get 2013/07/17/004 twice.

Is there a way to avoid this, either in SQL or .Net?  Are locks the only way, those would slow performance correct?

Comment: You should do the `select` and `update` in the same transaction, and lock the table until the `update` is complete. This way only one user can access the table at a time, and the other users wait for the transaction to complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the application to be able to scale, you're going to want to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE DayCounter (
    LastReset DateTime NOT NULL,
    NextValue INT NOT NULL
)
```

Then, you'll need a `FUNCTION` so you can get the next available value at will:

```
CREATE FUNCTION NextCounter()
    RETURNS CHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @LastReset DATETIME
        DECLARE @NextValue INT

        SELECT @LastReset = LastReset FROM DayCounter
        IF (DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @LastReset)) = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())
            UPDATE DayCounter SET LastReset = GETDATE(), NextValue = 1

        SELECT @NextValue = NextValue FROM DayCounter
        UPDATE DayCounter SET NextValue = NextValue + 1
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN RIGHT('000' + CAST(@NextValue AS CHAR), 3)
END
```

So now you can build an update statement that strings together your value, but it's safe from collisions **and** it manages resetting daily.

Comment: Does using Transactions make it safe from collisions?  If not, then what if 2 users hit that function at the same time, isn't there a chance they will get the same counter?

Comment: @Paritosh, by entering the transaction it locks the table and keeps a dirty read from occurring. Therefore this removes the chance for a collision.

Comment: There is no good reason to move business logic into the database. All logic should stay together in one layer

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, 1st : the function does not bring any added value, 2nd : the database tier is the hardest to scale, so the logic should stay in a business layer or basically in any other tier than the database tier, last : you cannot unit test a sql function so it should be a last resort, especially to solve a business requirement (here I consider creating a new entry each day a business requirement)

Answer (score 1):

First I would put a transaction surrounding the select AND the update.

Second I would only update using optimistic disconnected lock (meaning `update table where key = TheKey and reqNumber = TheValueYouSelectedToCount`), and make sure you have one row updated. If you have 0 row updated, it means that somebody else updated it already.

This way you cannot "loose" an update

Answer (score 1):

If reqNumber must be unique, then the database should have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column.  Adding this gives you another option: try once without the lock and if the insert fails, try again using a lock.  With a high read/write ratio and low collision frequency this can perform much better than the transaction-every-time solution.